# Java - Skip first line while using try with resources

Tags: java, java-8, java-io

I need to skip the very first line of what is found in the file. My code:

```
List<String> readStuff() {
    String pathName = "D:/java/eclipse/someStuff.txt";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathName))) {
        list = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load file.");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just invoke [`skip(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) to skip the first n-th element from the stream. In this case, using `skip(1)` would skip the first line.

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathName))) {
    return lines.skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```